# Why doesn't the MIT license have "patent use" permission?

Tags: mit, patents

From https://choosealicense.com/licenses/ and https://choosealicense.com/appendix/ I notice that the MIT license doesn't have "patent use" permisson like other popular open source licenses.

What does it indicate? What's the difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The MIT and BSD licenses were drafted before software patents were common. Therefore, they completely ignore the topic. For users of MIT- or BSD-licensed software, this creates the risk of a kind of *submarine patents*. A rights holder could release software involving patented technology under such an open-source license, and later try to sue users for their patent violation.

This absence of any mentions of patents has been construed by some as an *implicit* patent license. If someone releases software to the public, then surely they must have intended for that software to be used by the public, despite any patents? Although not completely unreasonable, that is a rather shaky argument. Some kinds of implied patent licenses have been upheld by U.S. courts. However, that observation ignores that open source is a global phenomenon, and most users (including myself) are not under the jurisdictions of U.S. courts.

Some projects have clarified the MIT and BSD licenses with an explicit patent grant. For example, React from Facebook used to be licensed under the BSD + a separate patent license between 2014 and 2017. The terms of this patent grant disproportionally favoured Facebook over users and made the combined license incompatible with many other open source licenses. After a few rounds of user outcries, they relicensed under a standard MIT license, without any explicit patent grant.

The Apache 2.0 License (and later the GPL 3) introduced an explicit patent grant to the user that only terminates if that user starts any patent litigation that claims that the licensed work were infringing. This approach improves clarity through an *explicit* patent grant and deters patent trolling, thus protecting other contributors and users. In my opinion, this makes the Apache 2.0 license vastly preferable to licenses like ISC, MIT, or BSD variants that ignore patents.

Comment: So what you are saying is MIT is like: Use the code however you want but when you fork it we may sue you... That is essentially on purpose misleading.

Comment: @Ini Part of the problem here is that an open source license should be valid in all jurisdictions, which differ in whether implied or non-express licenses can even exist. That "without restriction" part is seen by some as an express patent license even though the word patent isn't mentioned. There is also an argument based on the estoppel concept in common law. Modern licenses tend to avoid these problems and include an explicit patent grant; where MIT/BSD style licenses are used by entities with many patents you might see them amend the license with a clarification.

Comment: But you only have to care about the laws of the juristriction where you live in, right?

Comment: @Ini Yes, the license must first be legal in the author's jurisdiction. But I want the software that I write in Germany to be legally usable in the US, Quebec, China, and elsewhere. So I should use a license that is valid in all of these jurisdictions. That is really tricky but thanks to the Berne convention and WIPO there's at least some agreement about the concept of copyright. So most open source licenses derive their enforceability from copyright law (which is internationally harmonized) and not from contract law (which differs *wildly* between jurisdictions).

Comment: One specific problematic area is the public domain. In the US works can be actively placed in the PD. In Germany, works can only land in the PD if the copyright term expires. That means I am legally unable to contribute to PD-"licensed" projects! If I were to modify such a project, I'd have to instead use a fallback license that is functionally equivalent to a PD dedication (e.g. CC0).

Comment: What does it mean to place something actively in the PD –– do you sign something in order to do that or just attach some text? At first glance it makes sense to me to have a copyright on the code that I write and that I can govern this code with a license and give the world permission to do some things and not to do other things.

Comment: Do you suggest to not fork MIT and BSD license code? That would be pretty much everything javascript based, which is quite a bit. I mean seriously any jurisdiction which does not see an implicit patent clause in MIT is not sane. I mean I cannot make code available for the only purpose to sue somebody in case he/she forkes it.

Comment: @Ini Since copyright is automatic, PD status should be explicitly noted. Just writing "public domain" in place of a copyright notice should be enough in the US. My opinion on MIT/BSD is that Apache 2 should be preferred unless GPLv2 compatibility is desired, though either choice will be fine in practice. Your argument "you cannot make code available just to sue them later" assumes the existence of Estoppel, but that's only a thing in common law jurisdictions like the US/England. Other jurisdictions might only have clauses that demand good faith from all parties, without an implied license.

Comment: Could you exlaborate more on your last paragraph: "*The Apache 2.0 License (and later the GPL 3) introduced an explicit patent grant to the user that only terminates if that user starts any patent litigation that claims that the licensed work were infringing.*" Did you mean "[...] if that user starts any patent litigation that claims that **its derivatives** were infringing."? The original text sounds like "the original work is the one that were infringing", by a non-English-native reader like me.

Comment: @Rainning I did mean the original, though it also works with derivative works. Consider a software by author A. A holds patents which are used by the software. Through the license, all users of the software have received the necessary patent license from A and are safe from being sued by A. Now consider a troll T who uses the software, but also starts litigation claiming that the software infringes T's patents. Under Apache-2.0, this would terminate A's patent license to T. Under GPL-3.0, the entire license from A to T would be terminated.

Comment: So, even if A does infringe T's patent(s), the Apache-2.0 license is meant to protect A from both providing and being sued by its users, am I correct? Whether or not I am correct in this conclusion, I found your example very great and maybe you could add it to your answer.

Comment: @Rainning Strictly speaking, this termination clause doesn't protect authors or recipients/users. An Open Source license can't give a license for other people's patents. But it *discourages* patent trolling, since otherwise the troll wouldn't be able to safely use the software themselves. This is not really relevant for niche projects, but vitally important for large-scale projects like Android or Kubernetes.

Comment: @Ini > _Use the code however you want but when you fork it we may sue you_ < Per the answer on this question, the MIT license doesn't "exactly" work that way; its ambiguity is just an artifact of its time... however, at least one popular alternative, Creative Commons' CC0, has a clause which resolves the ambiguity the opposite of how Apache did: by clarifying that it actually works **exactly** "that way"; it contains a patent *limitation*, which reserves the right to sue people for forking your code if it implements any patents of yours (even if you didn't disclose these in-tree!)

Answer (score 9):

[According to RedHat](https://opensource.com/article/18/3/patent-grant-mit-license), who happens to be a prominent participant in FOSS IP litigation, the clauses `to deal in the Software without restriction` and `including without limitation` already expressly grants patent rights, at least under US law.

Comment: Facebook apparently agrees, since they replaced their controversial "BSD+patent" license for React with straight MIT.